# manage.py runserver is frequently reloading in production

Tags: python, django, reloading

I wrote a Django 2.2 program that works well in my PC running Windows 10 and my VPS, running CentOS 7.

When I changed some code in three files, the application continues to work locally but behaves strangely in prouduction.

When I run

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

on my server, I get this following response:

```
***\a.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader


***\b.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader


***\c.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader


***\a.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader


***\b.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

I modified these files before deploying, but they shouldn't be changing while the site is running.

Adding the `--noreload` flag prevents this:

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload 0.0.0.0:80
```

Why is this required?

Comment: Why are those files changing in the first place?

Comment: I edit it,need new code

Answer (score 3):

[`manage.py runserver` is only meant for development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Add a WSGI server like Gunicorn, Waitress, or uWSGI to your dependencies and run *that*, [e.g.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/):

```
gunicorn myproject.wsgi
```

Typically, to deploy Gunicorn in production you wouldn't bind directly to port 80 but instead [use something like Nginx](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html).

Comment: Thank you! It can't work in uwsgi,so I test it in the command line

Comment: @betterpan, I don't understand. Did this work or not?

Comment: Thank you!  It work in windows10 ,but can't work in centos7 shell .

Comment: It reloading forever,with out "--noreload"

Comment: ...but you shouldn't be using `manage.py runserver` on the server at all. Did you try what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: I used UWSGI before I edit the program,but uwsgi show error info after I edit the program code...I write a question like [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485511],but can't post now...

Comment: That's no excuse to use `manage.py runserver` in production. Ask about your _actual problem_, not whatever you think the solution is. Please read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: I think a correct program code should be run in 'manage.py runserver',even in vps...I did't use it for a long time...Thank you

Comment: @betterpan, no, `manage.py runserver` should _not_ be used in production. It's weird that you're getting the reloading, but it's also _irrelevant_. _Do **not** use `manage.py runserver` on your server_.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you help me about this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61158883

Answer (score 0):

When you run Django program in production, Please change the option of DEBUG = True to DEBUG = False in settings.py.