# sqlite3 works well in centos7 and python shell,but can't work in Uwsgi

Tags: python, django, sqlite, uwsgi

I have a question need your help~

I have a django program run in a vps(centos7,django2.2),it works well with Nginx+Uwsgi.

I edit three files(like a.py b.py c.py),and upload to the vps by winscp.exe,the program can't work now.

I found these logs in the uwsgi.log file.

```
  File "/mnt/datasource/<privacy_hidden>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 68, in <module>
    check_sqlite_version()
  File "/mnt/datasource/<privacy_hidden>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 65, in check_sqlite_version
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17).
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

I wrote "sqlite3 --version" in centos7 shell, it show version = 3.30.1

I wrote "python   >>> import sqlite3  >>>print sqlite3.sqlite_version" it show version=3.30.1

I wrote "python manage.py runserver --noreload 0.0.0.0:80",it works well, no info show sqlite error.

But the program can't work in uwsgi,I think the uwsgi.ini is correct.

What can I do ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved this question.

In centos shell:

```
> mv /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6_old
> cp /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```

then it's ok

Comment: May also need to update the short name:
`rm /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0 && ln -s /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57149324/6079380 + your answer solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

uwsgi has `RPATH` set. and its' `/usr/lib64`, and the old sqlite library is in this directory, you need to use the newer sqlite library in /usr/local/lib.

you could recompile uwsgi like this: `sudo LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib" pip3 install uwsgi`.

refrence: https://sourceexample.com/en/1c4153d4c3d4e65dac45/